# how to print the result of a bash script on a webpage using django rest framework

Tags: python, django

i'm new to django (DRF), i want to print the result of a script "myscript.sh" using a view and a template.
I tried the following but it doesn't work :

In myapp/views.py :

```
class TestView(TemplateView):
  template_name = 'index.html'
  def application(environ, start_response):
      start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
      proc = subprocess.Popen("./myscript.sh", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      line = proc.stdout.readline()
      while line:
          yield line
          line = proc.stdout.readline()
```

In myapp/templates/index.html:

```
<html>
      <head>
            <title> Lines </title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <p> {{ line }} </p>
      </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are not using anything from DRF here, just plain Django.

Secondly, a view in Django (or any other framework) is not by itself a WSGI application. There is no point defining an `application()` method, as the view will never call it.

Finally, you can't use yield to return an iterator, but at the same time expect to render a template.  A template is rendered in one go, so you need to have all the data for the template.

Rather than yielding line by line, you should return all the response at once, in a single list variable. You should do this within a `get_context_data` method, which returns a dict containing that list. Then, in your template, you would iterate over that list.

Comment: for the view :
class executView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'execut.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(executView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['list']  = subprocess.check_output("./wtm.sh", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
        return context

and for the html : 
<html>
<head>
  <title> Response </title>
</head>
<body>
  {% for element in list %}
  <p> {{ element }} </p>
  {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i use yield because i want to see the process of the execution of the script because it takes a while to complete. I modified my code using get_context_data and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Might you have forgot to return `response` from view

```
return Response({"line": line})
```

Comment: Thank your answerPython but we shouldn't use return while using get, if we did it we'll get a SyntaxError: (“'return' with argument inside generator”,)